# WPF Drawing on a ListBox

Tags: wpf, canvas, listbox, custom-controls

In a ListBox derived CustomControl I need to draw lines joining ListBoxItems that are layed out in a Canvas ItemsPanel.
I can achieve this by having class ListBoxLines : UIElement that does drawing in OnRender and then including that object in my ListBox ControlTemplate (but to do that I need to pipe the listbox contents to that class...)

```
<ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type p:NetworkVisualization}">  
    <Grid>  
        <p:ListBoxLines/>
        <ItemsPresenter/>
    </Grid>
</ControlTemplate>
```

Im just wondering if there is an easer way.  Id really just like to add my draw code directly to my ListBox derived class but if I do that it seems to draw UNDER the listbox canvas white background.
**Is there any way to to custom listbox drawing directly in my derived listbox class?**
EDIT: The motivation for this question is a custom control to display nodes and linkstrengths of a wireless mesh network as in the image below:[image]
EDIT: Additional issue:  The OnRender code for ListBoxLines (the node links) is cached - how to force a redraw of this when a node is dragging?  Ideally i want to build the cache with the all lines except for the currently dragging nodes lines and only redraw while dragging the lines to that node - not sure how to go about that.

Comment: Can you post an image of what you want to achieve? Before spending time on an answer, I would like to make sure we're on the same page.

Comment: Dennis Ive edited org post to show what I want to do.  The nodes are the listbox contents/items - I have to draw the link lines and strengths separately.  I am toying with the idea of abondoning the ListBox approach and just working with a CustomControl derived directly from Canvas - but the idea of selecting and selected item that listbox provides fits quite well with what Im doing (I want user to be able to select a node and interact with it) - so just trying to see if that is going to workout or not.  I would very much appreciate any input you have.  Cheers.

Comment: Search me on Google, then drop me an email, so I'll send you some code privately. I hope you're not in a hurry: I'll try to manage something during the launch break. Cheers

Answer (score 2):

Thanks for updating the question - from the original description we were on *completely* different pages.

---

Personally I would **not** implement a control like this, as I *know* from prior experience that it is not easy task. In the last <s>two</s> three occasions where I have needed charting I have used middle-ware solutions.

The argument for middleware is an easy case to make:

1. It will save you significant development time.
2. You will get results quicker, allowing you focus on your specific requirements.
3. Even if you choose a commercial provider, the time saved equates to money.

I recently evaluated charting middleware options for a project less than 5 months ago so I can tell your directly that for a WPF application the best libraries are:

- [Mindscape Diagrams 2](http://www.mindscapehq.com/products/wpfdiagrams) (Commercial)
- [Chart#](http://chartsharp.codeplex.com/) (Codeplex Project, Microsoft Public License)

I have used both products for studio applications (internal, however released as if the users were clients).

...

Take a look at the above solutions, come back with further questions (if any) and *then* if you still want to write your own I will at the very least point you in the direction and resources to do.

---

A side note, you say that you like the selection part of the `ListBox` - did you know that the selection functionality is actually supplied by the `Selector` base class?

Comment: Dennis thanks for getting back to me.  Using third party solutions is appealing and I had a look at the ones you mentioned but Im worried that I just won't have the level of control to get the look and control over interaction that I need from a product that is designed to cover a very broad specturm.  The app Im developing is a key component of the companys product - they are willing to invest to get it right.  Id very much appreciate any pointers you could give.  Ive updated the question to include an issue about drawing link lines while dragging nodes.  Thanks for you input.

Comment: Ricibob, I can appreciate the concern about being limited by a product but I can assure you that with the Mindscape product you should be able to achieve what you're looking for. This is both because we designed the product to be flexible but also because WPF provides such a flexible base itself! We're happy to help with any implementation questions you have too. John-Daniel Trask (Co-founder, Mindscape)